# Search Text and highlight it

Tags: c#, aspose.pdf

My code is in C#
I am using Aspose to search text and highlight it in pdf.
It is working but the time taken is very huge.
Example : My document has 25 pages and it has 25 instance of search text , 1 search text in each page.
It take 2 minutes which is unacceptable.

I have 3 questions:

1. Is it a way to reduce this time taken ?
2. Currently this approach is for pdf, in my case i have all types of doc (xls, pdf, ppt, doc)? Is there any way where this search and highlighting can be performed in all docs ?
3. Is there some better way of doing it other than aspose ?

---

```
// open document
Document document = new Document(@"C:\TestArea\Destination\SUP000011\ATM-1B4L2KQ0ZE0-0001\OpenAML.pdf");

//create TextAbsorber object to find all instances of the input search phrase
TextFragmentAbsorber textFragmentAbsorber = new TextFragmentAbsorber("Martin");

//accept the absorber for all the pages
for (int i = 1; i <= document.Pages.Count; i++)
{
    document.Pages[i].Accept(textFragmentAbsorber);

    //get the extracted text fragments
    TextFragmentCollection textFragmentCollection = textFragmentAbsorber.TextFragments;

    //loop through the fragments
    foreach (TextFragment textFragment in textFragmentCollection)
    {
        //update text and other properties
       // textFragment.TextState.Invisible = false;

        //textFragment.Text = "TEXT";
        textFragment.TextState.Font = FontRepository.FindFont("Verdana");
        textFragment.TextState.FontSize = 9;
        textFragment.TextState.ForegroundColor = Aspose.Pdf.Color.FromRgb(System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
        textFragment.TextState.BackgroundColor = Aspose.Pdf.Color.FromRgb(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
        //textFragment.TextState.Underline = true;
    }
}

// Save resulting PDF document.
document.Save(@"C:\TestArea\Destination\SUP000011\ATM-1B4L2KQ0ZE0-0001\Highlightdoc.pdf");
```

Comment: Where is the time being spent? Highlighting the text, or finding it?

Comment: HIghlighting it...foreach loop takes time as it needs to traverse all the textfragment

Comment: @user662285 we request you to please share your sample PDF document with which you are facing performance issue. You may please upload it to some public file sharer e.g. Dropbox, Google Drive and share the link here. We will test the scenario in our environment and address it accordingly. I am Asad Ali and I work for Aspose as Support Developer.

Comment: @AsadAli : I cannot upload that pdf as it contains confidential data. Can you please let me know same like pdf , can this functionality(search and highlight) be done for ppt, doc, xls and other documents ?

Comment: @user662285 Please note that we need sample PDF document in order to reproduce the issue in our environment so that it can be addressed accordingly. Regarding your second part of query, you can definitely achieve the feature using other Aspose APIs e.g. (Aspose.Words, Aspose.Cells and Aspose.Slides). Moreover, we have shared our detailed feedback to your similar inquiry in Aspose Forums. You may please check it for further details as we also shared our suggestions for document sharing there.

Comment: @AsadAli, How does it highlight more than one search text on each page?

Comment: @Eric The TextFragmentAbsorber Class can be used at the page level as well. In order to search more than one text phrase/word, you need to loop through every page and use TextFragmentAbsorber instance with new search text to find. Once the text is found, you can either highlight it by specifying Background Color or adding a highlight annotation. Furthermore, please try to post such inquiries and issues (if you face any) in our support forum (https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf) where they will be addressed appropriately and you would also be able to share your files securely there.